# ios-charts: Is it possible to show more values in marker

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

I am using [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in swift language. I need to show more data when clicking on every circle in LineChart. I can only show one value (Y axis - in image : price without dollar sign). Is it possible to implement below image? More values, empty circles, and fill circle when clicking.

[image: LineChart that I need]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @DevB2F  do you need answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can. Marker can show anything you want as long as you prepare the data. You need to figure out how to pass them into marker. e.g. subclass chart marker and modify draw() to draw your values. **ChartDataEntry** has an initializer with 3 parameters (x, y, data). You can pass more values in data, when clicking on an item **refreshContent** from **BalloonMarker** will call. **entry** parameter is all of your needs.

```
open override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)
{
    setLabel("\(entry.data as! String)\n \(String(entry.y))")
}
```

Visit [BalloonMarker.swift](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/0a56492109e95a40ab9dd67e6eb91536df22e793/ChartsDemo/Classes/Components/BalloonMarker.swift) on github

Comment: is there a tutorial on this anywhere?  I went through the official git project and all the charts but couldn't find how to modify this to include extra "data".  Thanks for the above answer.  Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately there isn't any tutorial. This library is based on [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki). You should study it's doc or study the ios library to find understand how it works.